# Java Integer.ValueOf method equivalence in C# With Radix Parameter

Tags: c#, java, migration

My task is to migrate this Java code to a C# version, but I'm having trouble with the `ValueOf` method, since I can't seem to find a equivalent version for C# (because of the `Radix` parameter used on Java, 16 in this case).

```
public String decrypt_string(String s) 
{
  String s1 = "";
  int i = s.length() / 2;
  int[] ai = new int[i];

  for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) 
  {
    // This is the "problematic" line \/
    ai[j] = Integer.valueOf(s.substring(j * 2, j * 2 + 2), 16).intValue();
  }

  int[] ai1 = decrypt_block(ai, i);

  for (int k = 0; k < i; k++) 
  {
    if (ai1[k] != 0)
      s1 = s1 + (char)ai1[k];
  }

return s1;
```

}

Here is my try, but it failed:

```
public String decrypt_string(String s)
    {
        String s1 = "";
        int i = s.Length / 2;
        int[] ai = new int[i];

        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            int startIndex = j * 2;
            string tmp = s.Substring(startIndex, 2);
            ai[j] = Int32.Parse (tmp); 
        }

        int[] ai1 = decrypt_block(ai, i);

        for (int k = 0; k < i; k++)
        {
            if (ai1[k] != 0)
                s1 = s1 + (char)ai1[k];
        }
        return s1;
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Any reason for the Down Vote ?

Comment: I would guess the downvote is because you did not explain about what you are trying to do, and just assumed one would know what the 16 means in the java code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are trying to parse a hexadecimal (base-16) number, use this:

```
int.Parse (tmp, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to convert a string to an integer, given that the string is in a specific base.

```
int i = Convert.ToInt32(str, 16);
int j = Convert.ToInt32("A", 16); // 10
```

So:

```
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        int startIndex = j * 2;
        ai[j] = Convert.ToInt32(s.Substring(startIndex, 2));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The radix is on Integer.valueOf(), not s.substring() in the java code you show there, so this would become:

```
ai[j] = Int32.Parse(s.Substring(j * 2, j * 2 + 2), 16);
```